# Why am I getting 405 code for Time Estimates while I can get 200 code for Product Types

Tags: ios, https, uber-api

I am using [UberKit](https://github.com/borischou/UberKit) which was working very good for me until yesterday.

I can successfully make a GET request to fetch `Product Types` (returns 4 types of car and `200 code`) but cannot fetch `Time Estimates` data (returns NO error, NO data but `405 code`).

According to [Uber API Reference page](https://developer.uber.com/v1/api-reference/)

```
401 Unauthorized the request requires user authentication (not logged in).
```

But also according to them, the `Product Types` as well as `Time Estimates` do not need access token and as a matter of fact, I do can fetch the `Product Types` data without access token mentioned above.

So did anybody else here meet this situation before, thanks.

Comment: Today I tested the `Product Types`, `Price Estimates` and `Time Estimates`, only `Time Estimates` gave me `401 code` while others returned good `200 code`. Is there anyone else facing the same problem? If so, I guess the issue could be on Uber's side.

Comment: Has anyone else faced this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048746/uber-api-endpoints-not-working-with-real-server-domain-but-working-well-with-san) is another similar question I posted and I have got the answer from Uber support officially.

It turned out that in my location, which is China, the full production Uber API has not been fully launched.

That's why anyone in China would get such weird response codes.